# Set paper-tooltip from dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In html `paper-tooltip` works fine like

```
<div>
  Text
  <paper-tooltip>The tooltip</paper-tooltip>
</div>
```

But howto build a`paper-tooltip` from dart?

```
DivElement divText = new DivElement();
divText.text = 'Text from dart';

PaperTooltip pT = document.createElement('paper-tooltip');
//How to set the tooltip String "The tooltip" on pT?

divText.append(pT);
```

I have tried to set the underlying content of `paper-tool`, but don't succeed. Anyone with a tip on how this maybe could be done?

Comment: What about `pT.text = "The tooltip"`?

Comment: Thanks. When I set with `pT.text = "The tooltip"` is seems to destroy some part of the `paper-tooltip` element and the element is displayed as div like element.

Comment: With a html created `paper-tool` the content can be modified with (getting underlying content)   `DivElement eToolDiv = pT.$['tooltip'];
eToolDiv.text = 'from dart';`  So the problem seems to be creation or append.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on here. Seems like the creation from dart with  `document.createElement('paper-tooltip');` don't give a proper `paper-tooltip` element.

Found an ok workaround by wrapping the `paper-tooltip` with a custom element. The custom element can be then created with `document.createElement('papertooltip-wrap');`

Html

```
<dom-module id="papertooltip-wrap">
  <template>
    <paper-tooltip>[[tooltipText]]</paper-tooltip>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Dart

```
@PolymerRegister('papertooltip-wrap')
class PapertooltipWrap extends PolymerElement {

  @property
  String tooltipText;

  PapertooltipWrap.created() : super.created(){
  }

  void setAnchorElement(Element e, final String tipText){
    set('tooltipText', tipText);
    append(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember all the Polymer elements have a factory constructor. You should be able to just `new PaperTooltip()`.

Comment: Great, I didn't knew, this gives more clear code. Thanks.